# In a .NET/C# context, what is a binary search and how/why can I use one?

Tags: c#, .net, binary-search

I've read about binary searches on Wikipedia for the first time today and just skimmed the surface a bit. It seems it's used to find items in a collection quickly where memory is sparse.

In a .NET/C# context, would I ever need to use one? Do you ever use them while building production actual-real-world software?

I'm sorry if this questions comes off as inciting, but I'm asking a genuine question as a student!

Comment: You would use a binary search in .NET for exactly the same reasons you would use one on any other platform.

Comment: Please don't change the title, I wrote C# on purpose because I need answers relevant to the language (if any). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<T>` has a [BinarySearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh.aspx) method, as does [Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb.aspx).  You would use them if you had a sorted list and needed to find an element.  Because they return an index, you can do things you can't with a straight dictionary like find the largest element less than a key.

One place I've used a binary search in real-world software is for doing range searches.  Shipping rates are given for weight range, so there might be one rate for 0-1 lb, one for 1-5 lb, and one for 5-10 lb.  If I call `List<T>.BinarySearch` and look for 4 lb, it will give me the first index higher than 4 lb, which I can use the find the 1-5 lb range.  A dictionary would just tell me that 4 lb was not found.

For general sorted data, you are often better off using [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) or [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Binary searches only work on sorted data, so as long as you have some collection of data in C# that you know is sorted, you can do a binary search on it.  Your best bet would be to use the implementations that are already provided (such as `List<T>.BinarySearch()`), but if the particular collection you're using doesn't have a binary search method, you can always write one.

Here's an example using the built in libraries:

```
// An ordered list of ints
List<int> ints = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 8, 20, 30, 44 };

// Search for 5 in the list
int ix = ints.BinarySearch(8);

// Display the index the element 8 was found at
Console.WriteLine(ix);
```

And yes, you would definitely want to use a binary search when you're searching sorted data.

Comment: What do you mean with 'diplay the index element 5 was found'? There is no five in your List.

Comment: Thanks for catching the type.  I meant to say 8, the element that was searched for.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime ago (while I was a student in the Computer Engineering course) I had to work with search algorithms. The result of such coursework was a paper.

I posted on my blog about [Quicksort and Binary Search algorithms in C++](http://www.leniel.net/2008/05/quicksort-binary-search-algorithms-c.html). Although it's in C++ code it should provide you with the **how/why** to use binary search. It also shows how to implement the binary search algorithm. There's a sample application provided so that you can test it by yourself.